# Android, перехват звонка, и перенаправление его по сети

Tags: java, android

Каким способом можно перехватить звонок на Android, и перенаправить его на ПК, нашел как позвонить с помощью своего приложения, но нужно что бы звук и само общение проходило посредством Android -> wifi(VPN) -> PC, така функциональность есть у airdoid, буду признателен за подсказку, в каком направлении двигаться

Answer (score 0):

Можете поробовать воспользоваться [этим](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.gtalksms) (GTalkSMS), либо [этим](http://projectmaxs.org/). Оба работают через XMPP-сёрвер, и, скорее всего (не обещаю) вам удастся перенаправить звонок на компьютер.

Если это вам поможет, отметьте решением. Если нет - заминусуйте. Информацию нашёл в интернетах, на себе не проверял, что не отменяет того факта, что ответ может быть бесполезным.